# error texlive 2019basic of february 2020

Tags: mactex

after updating my tex system with the Tex Live utility on osx mojave, characters from textcomp disappeared. I had to trash /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty and rename the weirdly named textcomp-2018-08-11.sty that was sitting next to it into textcomp.sty . Now everything is back to normal. Any idea of what's going on here ?

Comment: Are you using BasicTeX? What format line do you have?

Comment: @JosephWright : I had a problem with typesetting the documentation for the Fourier package after that update. It has been reported to the maintainer of that package.

Comment: Do you have the option of switching from MacTeX-Basic to the full [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/) distribution? Incidentally, the most recent version of `textcomp.sty` is -- as of today -- dated `2020/02/02 v2.0m`. Version `2018-08-11` would seem waaaaay out of date.

Comment: the file is not weirdly named (and you should not rename it, that will break the latest latex release) files named `zzz-somedate.sty` are part of the rollback mechanism to implement the option to access previous versions.

Comment: @Mico try `kpsewhich textcomp-2018-08-11.sty` it's a rollback implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp-2018-08-11.sty
```

is a core part of the base latex release and should *not* be renamed.

As explained in LaTeX News 31 (`texdoc ltnews` or https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf) the functionality of `textcomp` is now essentially always available and you do not need to load the package in most cases.

There are some cases, especially for debugging, where the `[error]` or warn package options are still useful so `textcomp.sty` is still in the distribution, and if you absolutely need the original code then that may be loaded via the package rollback syntax

```
 \usepackage{textcomp}[=2018/08/11]
```

which will in turn load the file `textcomp-2018-08-11.sty`

It may be that your document has an incompatibility with the latest release, perhaps using the above form may be a workaround, but without seeing an example document that shows the problem it is impossible to say. Renaming the file will make your installation incompatible with standard LaTeX and is strongly to be discouraged.

To see the rollback in action try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}[=2018/08/11]

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

which should show a terminal output as below, showing the rollback to the 2018 version of `textcomp`

```
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02>
L3 programming layer <2020-01-31>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp-2018-08-11.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
```

Comment: I use MacTeX-Basic and Tex utility app to load missing packages. Sorry to the purists for the sloppy solution (i was getting mad). For what it's worth, i re-updated this morning and i now have the latest textcomp which incidentally points at the 2018 one. The following code works but if i comment the package loading i get "Undefined control sequence" (here's the log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7kbofpftcblg0r/essai.log?dl=0)

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}[=2018/08/11]
\begin{document}
I like to type \textonehalf
\end{document}

Comment: @NicolasBoccard your tex installation is rather messed up and inconsistent. textcomp was included in the format in LaTeX2e 2020-02-02 so if you have an older format and do not load the package the undefined errors are expected. If you have an up to date texlive 2019 then this will work but your format is `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`  so not only have you not got the 2020-02-02 format you have missed both the 2019 releases as well and have a format built from the 2018 sources.